# Windows Store dynamically add items into GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

Hee,

I'm currently trying to make a GridView which contains items within an Image and a textblock for a title. I want to add these dynamically.

After searching for an hour I got this:

```
<GridView 
    x:Name="grid" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="False"  
    Foreground="#DEFFFFFF" 
    SelectionChanged="GridView_SelectionChanged" Margin="0, 50, 0, 0" >
    <GridView.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="CollectionViewSource" x:Key="CollectionViewSource" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageBinder">
            <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Width="200" Height="200" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBinder">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Width="auto" Height ="auto" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.Resources>

</GridView>
```

I understand from reading that the Source attributes needs a class or something?  But I really don't understand how I can add Item dynamically to the grid this way, can someone explain that to me with a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of a class :

```
Public Class PiecePictureObject{
    Public String [Text] { get; set; }
    Public BitmapImage [Photo] { get; set; }
}
```

- Then create a **List of that class**
- Add elements to that list
- Affect your gridview `GridviewExample.DataContext = ListYouCreatedOfYourObject`

And the XAML

```
<GridView x:Name="grdPiecesImage" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="grdPiecesImage_SelectionChanged">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <StackPanel.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF443585" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </StackPanel.Background>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Height="45" FontSize="25" Padding="10"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding Photo}" Height="95" Width="250"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I would suggest using different words than Photo and Text such as PiecePhoto, PieceText

Make sure that the **names in your bindings are the same as your object**. If you are having trouble with getting the image from your files here is how I did it in VB.NET

```
    Public Async Function LoadImage(_folder As StorageFolder, _filename As String) As Task(Of BitmapImage)
        Try
            Dim file = Await _folder.GetFileAsync(_filename)
            Dim bitmapImage As BitmapImage = New BitmapImage()
            Dim stream As FileRandomAccessStream = CType(Await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read), FileRandomAccessStream)
            bitmapImage.SetSource(stream)
            Return bitmapImage
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Sorry about the inconveniance I currently don't have the time to translate to C#

If you are still having problems take a look at this : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/image-binding-in-gridview-and-listview-in-windows-8-apps-usi/

Comment: Sort of worked, got a purple image in return instead of a poster. I'm gonna try and fix it ;)

Comment: If you don't want the purple blueish color on take out the Stackpanel.Background. It is a style I used for my grid @JordiSipkens

Comment: Also make sure that the names in your binding are the same as the names in your object. Also I edited my answer adding some more information. @JordiSipkens

Comment: It was the binding that had a misspel, thanks for the help :)!